# Install pihole over bind9

Tags: sockets, dns, dnsmasq, bind9

I installed pihole over an existing bind9 installation. Now I can't start FTL:

```
pihole-FTL dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.0.2: Address already in use
```

Do i have to turn bind9 off, or may i change the port of bind9 (when pihole works, I dont need my bind9 anymore, but perhaps pihole needs bind9 - but I can't find anything about it (nothing about configfiles that still exists in Ubuntu 18.04).

---

#### attachement:

whole output:

```
# systemctl status pihole-FTL.service 
● pihole-FTL.service - LSB: pihole-FTL daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/pihole-FTL; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-09-28 21:18:59 CEST; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 21530 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/pihole-FTL stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21546 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/pihole-FTL start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 pihole-FTL[21530]: Not running
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: pihole-FTL daemon.
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: pihole-FTL daemon...
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 pihole-FTL[21546]: Not running
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 su[21581]: Successful su for pihole by root
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 su[21581]: + ??? root:pihole
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 su[21581]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user pihole by (uid=0)
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 pihole-FTL[21546]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.0.2: Address already in use
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 su[21581]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user pihole
Sep 28 21:18:59 ubuntu1804 systemd[1]: Started LSB: pihole-FTL daemon.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. I stopped bind9 and pihole-FTL. Then I restarted pihole-FTL again. Then it worked.
I disabled bind9 to make sure it won't bother me anymore.

```
systemctl stop bind9 pihole-FTL
systemctl start pihole-FTL
systemctl disable bind9
```